# Why on while(getchar()!=EOF) it iterates extra time?

Tags: c

I'm trying to count chars from input, and I noticed that `while(getchar()!=EOF)` produces an extra count, Is it because it counts the null-terminated from input?

This is my [code](https://pastebin.com/msLUX0me):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
 
#define LINE 5
#define MEM_SIZE 10
 
char *getInput(int *counter);
void printInput(char *input);
 
int main() {
    char *mainInput;
    int counter = 0;
    printf("Please enter your input:\n");
    mainInput = getInput(&counter);
    if (mainInput == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\n\n\nOutput:\n%s\n", mainInput);
    printf("number of chars: %d\n", counter);
    printInput(mainInput);
    free(mainInput);
    return 0;
}
 
char *getInput(int *counter) {
    char *p = (char *)malloc(MEM_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    char *q = p; /* backup pointer, if realloc fails to allocate, function will return last address values stored */
    int c;
    int temp_counter = 0;
    long current = 0, last = MEM_SIZE - 1;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (current >= last) {
            q = p;
            p = (char *)realloc(q, last + (MEM_SIZE * sizeof(char)));
            if (p == NULL) {
                printf("Memory allocation failed, printing only stored values \n");
                return q;
            }
            last += MEM_SIZE;
        }
        
        p[current] = c;
        temp_counter++;
        printf("number of chars: %d\n", temp_counter);
        ++current;
    }
    p[current] = '\0';
    (*counter) = temp_counter - 1;
    return p;
}
 
void printInput(char *input) {
    int i, j = 0;
    while (input[j] != '\0') {
        for (i = 0; i < LINE; i++) {
            if (input[j] == '\0')
                break;
            putchar(input[j]);
            ++j;
        }
        if (input[j] != '\0')
            putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @EugeneSh. added, i'm just having hard time copy-pasting from virtual machine

Comment: Then send the file to the host, and copy from there. This question needs a [mcve].

Comment: I wonder if carriage return + linefeed are counted as individual characters?

Comment: @SteveFriedl I'd guess it's just `\n` which is not accounted for.

Comment: Print the character returned by `getchar`, as a number. `printf("char %d\n", c)` I bet it's 10 (newline) or 13 (carriage return).

Comment: added a snippet and pastebin link @EugeneSh.

Comment: @Schwern it is 10, You're correct.

Comment: Why do you have temp_counter and current? They are always the same.

Comment: @stark, good point, I've just added the counter now, didn't think I could just use the index I already got

Comment: @Sheilem 10 is a newline, from when the user hits enter.